# select ifnull() won't let more than 1 column in the query

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I get this error - 1241, operand should contain 1 column(s), upon running the query below:

```
select ifnull((select col1, col2 from table where uid = num limit 1) , '0');
```

If I project only 1 column it runs without error, I actually want to use select `*` to project all the columns, but it's not working for than one column, please suggest me something.

Comment: The function innull requires only one input and you have two columns as input. Hence the error. But I think you understand this already. You can split the function for each column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `ifnull` over two column you could

or check for one column

```
select ifnull((select col1 from table where uid = num limit 1) , '0');
```

or use case  for eval  the content and return a single value

```
  select ifnull((select case when  col1 is null and  col2 is null then null else 1 end
          from table where uid = num limit 1) , '0');
```

Comment: Thanks ! I ran it for the two columns, it gave me the desired result. How would I do this for selecting all the columns, 'case' doesn't allow commas, should I write multiple 'case'. I have 15 such columns.

Comment: I have done this `select ifnull((select case when  col1 is null and  col2 is null and col3 is null and col4 is null and col5 is null then null else 1 end
          from table where uid = num limit 1) , '0'); `, and I did this for col1 to col15, it's running pretty fine. Do suggest if I am doing it in a wrong way, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:-

```
select ifnull(col1,'0'), ifnull(col2,'0') from table where uid = num limit 1
```

Comment: Thanks, up-voting your answer ! Runs pretty fast, but doesn't give a 0 upon encountering a non-existing uid value. Any pointers?

Comment: if you can provide some sample data and the kind of output you want for that data that will help to provide solution.